# Storing JWT as localStorage item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwt, frontend, local-storage

I am working on a chat-application, and after user logins,
I am storing complete user info in the localStorage like this:

[image]

I am also using JWT to authorize user.

So would it be better to store only the JWT in localStorage?
And retrieve the userInfo from backend using the JWT?
What is the optimal solution for this kind of thing?

Is it a good way to store the userInfo or should I use other ways like cookies?

Currently I have implemeted by storing the complete userInfo to localStorage, but I think its not a good practice.

So, your input is of much importance here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite common to store the JWToken in a cookie and even send said cookie to the server in requests (instead of adding the auth header).
Using a secure cookie (`HttpOnly`, `SameSite=strict`, `secure`) is more secure than localStorage, while there is *always* risks with storing credentials on the client.

When it comes to the user information, if it's not too much information you require, some of it could actually be stored in the JWT as a custom claim. That way, you don't need to fetch the "base data" from the database but rather just access it from the JWT when it's parsed (and validated).

Comment: JWT in cookie can also be compromised by an XSS attack. The right answer is to prevent an XSS attack from happening in the first place. Generally there is nothing wrong with storing JWT in localStorage.

Comment: Well, yes, anything stored on the client is possibly compromised. But a cookie with the `HttpOnly` `SameSite=strict` and `secure` flags should be about as safe as you can get if you wish to store it clientside.

Comment: And I fully agree that preventing xss attacks from happening is the thing to do. :)

Comment: I will remove the local storage note seeing it might give a false impression that cookies are fully safe.

Comment: No, it's okay - HttpCookies do make it significantly harder for an attacker. But with an XSS vulnerability you are just a little less screwed this way.